# Navigate inside master instead of detail in SplitView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, master-detail, splitview, ios-navigationview

I have a split view in my iPad ready app:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Show the slave view HERE", destination: SlaveView())
                    .navigationBarTitle("Master view")
            }

            Text("Detail view")
                .navigationBarTitle("DO NOT show the slave view here")
        }
    }
}
```

So I like the `SlaveView` view to open in the list itself, not in the detail view.
I have tried setting another `NavigationView` in the `Slave`, also a text below that, also setting all `navigationViewStyle`s on both and each `Master` and `Slave` with no luck.

This is the simplest Slave view you can have to make it build:

```
struct SlaveView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink("Sub Detail view", destination: Text("Sub Detail view"))
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Slave view")
    }
}
```

So how can I change the Master (left) view of the split view instead of the detail (right) view?

**Note that** this is a simplified reproducible code. The real project uses more complex lists for master and slaves and so on. Also, we don't want to loos navigation stuff like transitions, title transforming, back button and etc.

For more clarifying, I need this state in the flow:

[image: Needed step]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just modify link that it is not a detail

[image: demo]

```
NavigationLink("Show the slave view HERE", destination: SlaveView())
    .isDetailLink(false)
```

Comment: +1 for point to the right modifier. But it has a strange bug! Let me show you with a gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c09sb.gif. Just one click does this ‍♂️

Comment: It looks like you activate many links at once. Look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63012568/swifui-activates-all-available-indices-in-foreach) - visually you have something similar.

Comment: Looks like `.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())` cuse this issue.

Comment: I am eternally grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a `Button` instead of a `NavigationLink` and replace your master view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSlaveView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            masterView
                .navigationBarTitle("Master view")
            Text("Detail view")
                .navigationBarTitle("DO NOT show the slave view here")
        }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    @ViewBuilder
    var masterView: some View {
        if showSlaveView {
            SlaveView()
                .onTapGesture { self.showSlaveView = false }
        } else {
            Button("Show the slave view HERE") {
                self.showSlaveView = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the idea. But it kills all navigation transition, title transition, back button, swipe gesture, and so on. Also, in the complex app. Master and slaves are complex lists. What about that?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini But this would mean two NavigationLinks open at the same time. From the master you open the slave, but the detail is already opened (also from the master).  I don't think that SwiftUI navigation stack allows that currently.

Comment: I need something like: keep lists on the left and details on the right. But I think like you too, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `StackNavigationViewStyle()`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Show the slave view HERE", destination: SlaveView())
                .navigationBarTitle("Master view")
            
            Text("Detail view")
                .navigationBarTitle("DO NOT show the slave view here")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: This kills the entire `SplitView` and I don't want that. I think you miss understood the question.