# How does one use NavigationLink isActive binding when working with List in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

The use case is pretty simple. I have a List of places, and each corresponds to a geofence. I need to enable navigation in that particular row(s) whose geofence the user is inside. And the list is dynamic and is fetched from an API. There are similar question on Stackoverflow, but those address only static lists.

I tried using a dictionary of bools, but I am not able to make it work.

This is a simplified mock code:

```
struct ListView: View {
  @State private var navActive: [UUID: Bool] = [:]
  var body: some View {
    
           List (viewModel.allItems, id: \.id) { item in
           NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item), isActive: $navActive[item.id]) {
             Text(item.name)
             .onTapGesture {
                if currentLocation.isInside(item.geofence) { navActive[item.id] = true }
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I get this error: **Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Bool?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'**
on the NavigationLink isActive argument.

Note: I've populated the navActive dictionary with key-value pairs on receiving allItems with an onRecieve modifier

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use `NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item)) { Text(item.name) }`?

Comment: `isActive` is not very appropriate in such scenery, it is better to use tag/selection based constructor. You can see an example for same dynamic List in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63012828/12299030

Comment: @Asperi yea, I need to validate if the user is inside the clicked row's geofences and navigate only if he/she is inside it

Comment: That looks like it would solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a possible approach for your use-case

```
struct ListView: View {
    
    // ... your view model defined here

    @State private var selectedItem: UUID? = nil
    var body: some View {

        List (viewModel.allItems, id: \.id) { item in
            Text(item.name)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.selectedItem = item.id
                }
                .background(
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item), tag: item.id,
                        selection: $selectedItem) { EmptyView() }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great. Did not even know that the background modifier can be used like this.

Comment: Best approach for my case so far.. Have List with label which navigates to "Create" view, and if creation is success, navigate back.. Other solutions wouldn't provide proper clickable are or values change, and this definitely feels like a native solution for that case as it looks the same as embedding views in NavigationLink as usual.. Thanks