# Changing Navigation Link Style

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am fairly new to macOS development, especially using swiftUI. coming from a UIKit background, I find it hard to change the navigation link style (I only use a simple text)

here's an example

```
NavigationLink {
                Text("Ini Blue")
 } label: {
                Text("Ini papa")
 }
```

and here's what I got:
[image: The result of the code]

i want it to be a simple text because I wanted to add some other properties, are there an API or a way to solve it? thanks

Comment: A simple text wouldn't give the user the visual cues to know that they can tap on it but you can just use an onTapGesture and set a NavigationLink's isActive to true.

Comment: let's just say for an experiment, so how do I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63197064/how-does-one-use-navigationlink-isactive-binding-when-working-with-list-in-swift